# Docker GUI with Mac how to

Tags: macos, user-interface, docker

I am recently starting with docker and I am facing a problem in setting-up an existing docker-desktop image and showing is t on my screen.
This will be the first step to then personalize the whole image:

I followed instruction from several sites but the easiest one is the following:
[dockerfile/ubuntu-desktop](https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu-desktop)

- No problem in downloading the image
- When I run it I obtain the following output:

  ```
  $ docker run -it --rm -p 5901:5901 -e USER=root dockerfile/ubuntu-desktop     bash -c "vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 24 && tail -F /root/.vnc/*.log"
  You will require a password to access your desktops.
  Password: 
  Verify:   
  Would you like to enter a view-only password (y/n)? n
  New 'X' desktop is 0792f104dfd0:1
  Creating default startup script /root/.vnc/xstartup
  Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
  Log file is /root/.vnc/0792f104dfd0:1.log
  03/02/15 14:10:08 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
  03/02/15 14:10:08 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
  03/02/15 14:10:08 All Rights Reserved.
  03/02/15 14:10:08 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
  03/02/15 14:10:08 Desktop name 'X' (0792f104dfd0:1)
  03/02/15 14:10:08 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
  03/02/15 14:10:08 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
  Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/' not found - ignoring
  Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
  Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
  xrdb: No such file or directory
  xrdb: can't open file '/root/.Xresources'
  AUDIT: Tue Feb  3 14:10:09 2015: 17 Xtightvnc: client 6 rejected from local host
  ```

The container inspection output is the following:

```
    $ docker inspect -f '{{json .NetworkSettings }}' 0792f104dfd0 
    {"Bridge":"docker0","Gateway":"172.17.42.1",
    "IPAddress":"172.17.0.21","IPPrefixLen":16,
    "MacAddress":"02:42:ac:11:00:15",
    "PortMapping":null,
    "Ports":{"5901/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"5901"}]}}
```

When I try to connect with VCN I get errors.

Could you help me in finding what I should change to have a running, visible desktop on mac using Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just missing the .Xresources file try adding an empty file there.  [This discussion](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2011/02/msg00864.html) seems to imply that it is not really needed. You can add the file by using:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5901:5901 -e USER=root dockerfile/ubuntu-desktop \
    bash -c "touch /root/.Xresources && \
    vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 24 && \ 
    tail -F /root/.vnc/*.log"
```

Docker on OSX (and any non-linux OS) runs inside a boot2docker vm and that VM's network is not available on localhost outside the VM. To get to the network interfaces use the Boot2docker IP which your can retrieve using the `boot2docker ip` command. This IP is usually 192.168.59.103 although that is not guaranteed.

Comment: I tried it but still cannot access the desktop, even though the .Xresources line has disappeared.
Any advice about how can I verify if it's really transmitting?

Comment: What IP are you using in you VNC client

Comment: I tried with : 0.0.0.0:5901 and with 172.17.0.21:5901 with no luck in safari : [vcn://[ip]:[port]

Comment: Use boot2docker ip to get the correct IP it should be 192.168.59.103 or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my problem :)

Comment: np, I updated the answer so that anyone else reading it gets the context of the acceptance.